# AWS "Unsupported VMDK File Format"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter VM to AWS with

```
[
  {
    "Description": "My Server vmdk",
    "Format": "vmdk",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "docspot.pt",
        "S3Key": "image-2.vmdk"
    }
}]
```

, but I get the error

```
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "My server VM",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-0cd53d28529475328",
            "SnapshotDetails": [],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Disk validation failed [Unsupported VMDK File Format]",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
```

I can open the vmdk in my laptop, with vmware workstation player.
Any ideas why aws ec2 is not accepting my  vmdk?

Comment: how did you exported this image and from which source. You can check the [Image format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#prerequisites) supported.

Comment: I exported it from google cloud engine

Comment: HI @NunoFeliciano I am seeing the similar error. I too tried to use an vmdk made of a VM from GCE. Can you help on how you resolved this ?

Comment: Is `VMDK` case-sensitive perhaps?